# Why in URL <character before> #<charecter after> reads only <character before > only i Query String?

Tags: asp.net

If I pass

```
const string strEditParams = "TaskID={0}&TaskName={1}";
                string strEditValues = string.Format(strEditParams,
                                                    lbl.Text
                                                    , "$#hello"                                                    
                                                    );
                lnkBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return OpenEditTask('test.aspx?" + strEditValues + "')");
```

from page1.aspx to test.aspx, and in the page load of test.aspx if I do

```
if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            var pp = Request["TaskName"].ToString();

        }
```

I get only **$.**

Why in query string i am getting only $ in this case and not the full values of "TaskName" (characters before #) # and how to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In URLs, the `#` character introduces a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It has to be encoded to be used in the query string itself.

You can either encode it yourself:

```
string strEditValues = string.Format(strEditParams, lbl.Text, "$%23hello");
```

Or use [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx):

```
string strEditValues = string.Format(strEditParams, lbl.Text,
    Server.UrlEncode("$#hello"));
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `#` is a special character in URLs, it marks the fragment ID.

You have to encode it as `%23` to pass it as a parameter or use UrlEncode instead.

Your code could look like this:

```
lnkBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return OpenEditTask('test.aspx?" 
    + Server.UrlEncode(strEditValues) + "')");
```

That would correctly encode any special characters from `strEditValues`.

Comment: I even tried with Server.HtmlEncode(strEditValues) but no result.. please help

Comment: `HtmlEncode`doesn't help you here, you need `UrlEncode` instead.

Comment: And note you should always be URL-encoding any string you inject into a query string parameter. `#` is one character that will trip you up otherwise, but far from the only one.